# Spring @RequestBody working with Postman, but a 415 with javascript from browser

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I'm a starting web-developer and mostly done stuff with java on Spring boot. Just beginning to get familiar with javascript and right now having a problem that seems similar to many others here on stackoverflow, but the difference seems to be, that everything is working when POSTing with Postman, but when trying with browser via javascript, Il get a 415.

The
`alert(JSON.stringify(task))` gives (when "taskName"="walk"): `{"name":"walk"}`

When the same body is POSTed with Postman, the response is:

```
{
    "id": 65,
    "name": "walk",
    "new": false
}
```

Dependencies for jackson-databind, -core and  -annotations version 2.10.1 are in use.

The javacode:

```
var url = contextRoot + "tasks"
var http = new XMLHttpRequest()

http.onreadystatechange = function() {

    alert("readystatechange")

    //if (this.readyState != 4) {
    //    return
    //}
       
    document.getElementById("received").innerHTML = this.responseText
    
}

function addTask() {
   
    var task = {
    name: document.getElementById("taskName").value
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(task))

    http.open("POST", url)
    http.send(JSON.stringify(task))
}
```

My @RestController

```
@RestController
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @GetMapping("/tasks")
    public List<Task> list() {
        return taskRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/tasks", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public Task create(@RequestBody Task task) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        System.out.println(task);
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }
    
    /*@PostMapping("/tasks")
    public String create(@RequestBody String task) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        System.out.println(task);
        return "hilipataheijjaa";
    }*/
    
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Tasks</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Tasks</h2>
                
        <input type="text" id="taskName"/>
        <button onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>

        
        <p id="received">
        </p>

        <script th:inline="javascript"> var contextRoot = /*[[@{/}]]*/ '';</script>
        <script th:src="@{/javascript/tasks.js}" defer></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Task.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Task extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private String name;

}
```

The XMLHttpRequest.responseText:

> {"timestamp":"2021-06-21T08:27:33.989+00:00","status":415,"error":"Unsupported
> Media
> Type","trace":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:
> Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:227)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:422)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:367)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:110)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:59)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:395)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1234)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1016)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\n","message":"Content
> type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/tasks"}
>
> > Spring console:
> > 2021-06-21 11:27:02.189  WARN 5152 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> > [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
> > type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported] 2021-06-21 11:27:33.988
> > WARN 5152 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
> > .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> > [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
> > type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

**Thank You in advance!**

Comment: is javascript application is deployed with web-apis application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is obvious. => `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported`

```
//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

You can add this and try.

Comment: Thank You!! So simple... so many hours. Just had to put it after the ```http.open("POST", url)``` line.. tried first before it, and the code did not run any further than this new line.

Comment: If this answer worked for you, you can approve the answer.

Comment: I tried ”voting up”, but: ” Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.”. Is there another way to approve?

Comment: I don't know :D

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to realize that accepting an answer is different from upvoting. . Now its done.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot Application will return JSON format.

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(myArr);
}
};
```